# Does isomorphism of cohomology rings imply isomorphic cap products?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose that I have spaces $X$ and $Y$ with isomorphic cohomology rings. This implies that the cup product is the same (on the level of cohomology). Does this imply that the cap product structure is the same for the two spaces?

Alternatively, if I have the extra information that $\Sigma X \simeq \Sigma Y$, does this them imply that the cap product is the same?

Comment: I guess by "isomorphic cap products" you mean there exists an isomorphism on homology that together with your isomorphism on cohomology preserves the cap product?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: I think you can define the cap product in terms of the cup product, via the adjoint relation $\langle \beta \cap \alpha, \gamma \rangle = \langle \beta, \alpha \cup \gamma \rangle$. Since an isomorphism in cohomology gives an isomorphism in homology and maybe something about naturality of cap products (though naturality depends on there being a map $f:X \to Y$ that induces the isomorphism), I think this all works out, though I haven't actually thought through it.

Comment: @Osama Does that relation definitely hold on the level of Homology/Cohomology, rather than just on the level of chain complexes?

Comment: @Matt I think so, section D here sort of talks about it more http://people.math.gatech.edu/~etnyre/class/6441Spring20/SectionIII.pdf in particular lemma 9

Comment: I see. Thank you. Does the adjoint relation, on the level of homology/cohomology, definitely completely determine the cap product structure from the cup product structure?